# Make font in Google Chrome clearer, sharper

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, fonts, windows-10

Could anyone please help/tell me how to fix blurry fonts in Google Chrome? Note that ClearType doesn't help. ClearType is disabled. Seriously in Linux fonts are sharper, clearer also in Mac OS, but why not in Windows?

What have I tried:

[image: What I tried]

By setting registry entry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Control Panel > Desktop > FontSmoothing` to value **1**, font looks sharper, clearer, readable (**just as I want it**). But this works only if the webpage uses **Arial font**.

(I forced web page to use Arial font by using StyleBot extension)

[image]

Here is if the page uses its own fonts:

[image]

How can I make the clearer font for other fonts e.g. Source Sans Pro? Link from where the screenshot was taken: https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index.html (dashboard v1)

Using:

- Windows 10 x64
- Google Chrome 58.0.3029.81
- 24' inch led display @1920x1200

Comment: Have you zoomed the page? try pressing ctrl 0 to reset the zoom.  If that doesn't work, have you changed the font size in your browser settings so it is not using the default font size?  If that is default, then it may just be the font that the website decided to use is just rubbish at rendering - some fonts don't look great on the web.  Has the Source Sans Pro font been loaded by the website properly - ie using an @fontFace?

Comment: Ps, looks fine in my chrome

Comment: @Pete I tried zooming the page and the font looks very sharp, clean when zoomed at 300%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that having 24' inch led display @1920x1200 is the problem. I opened page https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index.html in laptop with 15,6' inch display with the same resolution 1920x1200 and the fonts are very clear and smooth.

I also went to store and tried to open page with [Lenovo ThinkPad T560](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Lenovo-ThinkPad-T560-Core-i7-940MX-3K-Notebook-Review.167770.0.html) which has resolution 2880x1620 and the fonts were also clear and smooth.

To have smooth and clean fonts monitor must have very high resolution. Went also to apple store and checked about their resolution: 3840x2160 -> therefore clean fonts

For now I solved it like this:

- set registry entry HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Control Panel > Desktop > FontSmoothing to value 1. Font looks sharper, clearer, readable (just as I want it). But this works only if web page uses Arial font.
- installed Google Chrome Extension [StyleBot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) with next css **global** style:

  ```
  div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, textarea
  {
    font-family: "Arial";
  }
  ```

So every page I open renders with Arial font, which is very clear.

Answer (score 3):

Try going to chrome://flags and setting **LCD text antialiasing** to Enabled. Then restart browser.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this issue was solved by **disabling**

```
"Use hardware acceleration when available"
```

option in Chrome's settings (is inside the System section).